# JTree updates in realtime?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, real-time, repaint

I'm looking for a threaded solution to updating my JTree every second.

Basically, I'm...

- Importing an external file
- Creating an Enumeration off of that
- Building the tree off the enumeration

The external file can change at random, and the data in the tree needs to represent this change in a somewhat reasonable time manner. How would I be able to have the tree redraw without repainting the entire content pane which the JTree (via a panel) is in?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Just have the JTree's model fire an update, and the JTree will repaint itself. The easiest way to do this is to use a DefaultTreeModel, and when the file changes, construct TreeNodes (possibly using DefaultMutableTreeNode) from your file, and call setRoot() on the model with the base node of your newly created node tree.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you probably read this somewhere else: Swing is not thread save ;). If you want to update a Swing component from a different thread anyway, you have to make that other thread push it's updates on Swing's event thread. The method to do this is EventQueue.invokeAndWait(Runnable).

Here's a code example for a similar problem (making a JTree sync with a directory tree):
http://www.onyxbits.de/content/java-and-directory-trees-joy-implementing-simple-filemanager

You should be interested in the FileMonitor.java file.

Comment: -1 for the link - perceived problems (except the inability to monitor changes to file system inside pure java) are based lacking knowledge about FileSystemView

Answer (score 1):

Try this if your tree uses the DefalultTreeModel

```
((DefaultTreeModel)yourTree.getModel()).reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you repaint the `JTree` component, the paint region will be clip out the rest of the containing panel.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like @Tom suggested if you have lots of nodes. The solution of @CarlG is probably fine for few nodes. If you update the entire tree model, every second you run into performance issues.

I would update only the visible bounds of the tree, if needed, and keep some AST(Syntax tree) somewhere. If the tree model(from the parsed document) is changing every second, I seriously doubt that the user will have time to scroll all the tree each second.

```
User scrolled to bounds XXX
A = First visible node
B = Last visible node
if someRangeBefore(A) is dirty update
If region(A, B) is dirty
  update nodes
```

It would be more complicated than above to implement a working and very efficient strategy to update nodes.